# Licenses & Permission sets

Tags: appexchange, permission-sets, licenses

just have quick queson regarding permission sets. I will create a package to publish in AppExchange with 10 user license to limit the number of users to the app and also I will have permission sets in my package too to define access areas for different type of users. So in this case should I relate licenses with those permission sets for them to be assigned to users ? Or what kind of approach should I use ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this answer, [Permission Set Licenses for ISVs](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfXcUAJ/permission-set-licenses-for-isv-managed-packages) is in development. For now, a package that has a limited number of licenses requires subscribers to assign both a license and permission set to each user.

Comment: Hello, so in this case should I create my permission sets with a license assigned or license and permission set could be independent?

Comment: update : actually as I understand License that I create via License Management App can't be assigned to permission set, so I guess they should be independent. Or is there another approach for that ? Thanks for your answers !

Comment: @HasanTokul Correct. The license and the permission set can't be linked together at this time. Admins will have to assign both the license and permission set.